# How do you sum up a specific row from an array?

Tags: c++

The user is asked what row they would like to check the total of a specific row (int subscript). It seems off, are there any errors?

```
int getRowTotal(int userFilledArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int subscript)
{
    int rowTotalSum = 0;
    
    for (int i = subscript; i == subscript; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++)
        {
            rowTotalSum += userFilledArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return rowTotalSum;
}
```

Comment: In your first for loop you assign `i` to `subscript` and your break condition is when `i` equals `subscript`: you never enter the first for loop. Edit: my bad, you enter the loop once but this outer loop isn't necessary.

Comment: @rubytox thats the condition to continue the loop; A single iteration gets executed; Adding this outer loop decreases code quality nonetheless. The outer loop should be removed and i should be replaced with `subscript` in the inner loop.

Comment: Yes I just understood that, that outer loop got me confused

Comment: Just use `subscript` as a row index

Comment: If you're going to just copy and paste a homework question, at least give us the courtesy of showing us what you have tried...

Comment: Btw: If you want to use the standard lib for this, you could just turn the function body into `auto row = userFilledArray[subscript]; return std::accumulate(row, row + NUM_COLS, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the brute force method:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int column = 0; column < NUM_COLS; ++column)
{
    sum += UserFilledArray[subscript][column];
}
```

There's also `std::accumulate` which is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)